# Today with present perfect

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

Is it possible or even acceptable to use the present perfect with today (in those cases when today refers to the present age)? Even native speakers seem to disagree!!
For instance; today, companies have thrived on foreign investment.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely yes. If you use the present perfect you are asserting a present relevance of what you are saying - often the meaning of that present relevance is that the events are seen as part of a process or period that is still continuing.

With literal "today":

> I haven't seen him today.

implies that I still might, whereas

> I didn't see him today.

implies that the possibility of seeing him is over - perhaps I was talking about at work today, but work has finished; or I know that he has been here and then left.

Similarly

> Companies have thrived on foreign investment.

means that I am thinking of this as a process which is continuing (more compaines will do so).

Sometimes a perfect and a non-perfect are both possible *in talking about exactly the same factual situation*, and express a difference in how the speaker is choosing in that moment to talk about the situation. So if I say

> Companies thrived on foreign investment.

I am saying that *for the purposes of the present discussion* I am regarding that as an situation which is not relevant to the present. That might mean that it is no longer happening. But it might mean just that I am considering only a historical period, and it is not relevant to me right now whether it is continuing or not.

Comment: /have not seen him today/ implies that you have not seen the person up to the point in time when you utter the sentence. Personally, when today is used to actually mean at present, I would not use it.

Answer (score 2):

Though I am not a native speaker, I think the present perfect can be perfectly used with 'today' (the day hasn't come to an end yet and you relate the past to the present moment), as in

I haven't seen Tom today.
It's been a hard day today.

However, I have heard a few American friends say things like-
I didn't eat anything today. 
I didn't see Tom today. (it was late and they saw the day as a completed event, like doing those things wouldn't be possible anymore).

I guess the present perfect could be slowly dying (AmE still prefers 'He just left' or 'I already ate'), but it's a great verb tense that I don't have in my first language (Portuguese) and I hope it never dies completely :)

Answer (score 0):

Today, can have two meanings:
It can mean /**at present or at the present time**/ or /**on this actual day**/.

The present perfect should be understood from a point on the (verbal) timeline that the action of the sentence is occurring in the present "at the time of speaking":

1) On this actual day:

We have not seen him today. [the day is not over and we haven't seen him yet, we might still see him]

2) at the present (time):

**Today (at the present time), companies have thrived on foreign investment**. That seems to me generate awkward meaning in English.

To be grammatical, it would have to be: **Until now, companies have thrived on foreign investment.**

However: the at present meaning could be used like this:
**Today companies have shown themselves to be flexible**.
Meaning: **At the present time companies have shown themselves to be flexible**.